# How to create an url from an absolute path in elm

Tags: url, single-page-application, elm

I want to create an url (not a link) for a text field for a share functionality.
Like for example the one stackoverflow uses

[image: des]

I already hava function that produces the path part for the url, like

```
toUrl : Route -> String
toUrl route = ...

toUrl (Home (Just "hallo")) --> "/?b=hallo"
```

and using this string for a link as a href attribute works, but I'm wondering how I could create a complete url from this string.

PS: I'm using a single page application so I get an `Url` at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you say is "the path part for the url" isn't actually just the path part, but the path *and query* parts of the URL. Ideally you'd separate them so you can create a well-formed URL representation:

```
{ initialUrl
    | path = "/"
    , query = Just "b=hallo"
}
```

But since it's just a record, with no validation, it'll work if you just use it as the path as well. At least if you later just use `Url.toString` on it. Other operations might cause unexpected results.

```
{ initialUrl | path = "/?b=hallo" }
```